# Mapping database table to class

Tags: c#, asp.net, orm, mapping

I'm writing an application with ASP.NET MVC2. In the tutorial I'm following for registration, the author mentions mapping a database table to my `User` class to make it easy to insert the user once they pass validation checks, but he doesn't explain how to do that.

These are the attributes of my `User` class:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

They have DataAnnotation validations as well. I also made a database table on a remote server (hosted at my University) called `Users` which has the following fields:

```
Id
Username
Email
Password
```

How can I map them and then easily save the user to the database?

Thanks.

Comment: What ORM are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: You can use Entity FrameWork or LINQ to SQL [Good if you are using SQL Database] or Microsoft.Practices.Unity. http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/07/20/the-short-example-about-entity-framework-4-ctp4-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some well known ORM solutions out there. I would recommend [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework). [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37932/Simple-Sample-with-Entity-Framework) code project example is good place to start

Answer (score 0):

You can try out:

**[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)**

LINQ to SQL is a component of .NET Framework version 3.5 that provides a run-time infrastructure for managing relational data as objects.

**[Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399408.aspx)**